# Overloaded '+' Operator Not Compiling

Tags: c++

I'm trying to understand the concept of operator overloading by writing some simple, silly tests. I thought this might be useful as this helps me understand C++ better.

Why does this example implementing a concatenation operator of `Animal` class and `std::string` not compile? G++ gives me the following error:

> extra qualification 'Animal::' on member 'operator+' [-fpermissive]

This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Animal {

public:
    string _type;
    string _name;
    string _sound;


    Animal & Animal::operator+(const string & o);
};


Animal & Animal::operator+(const string & o) {
    cout << "plus operator \n";
    this->_name=o;
    return *this;
}


int main( int argc, char ** argv ) {
    Animal a;

    a+"hhh";
    cout<<a._name;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This operator should be called `+=` or `<<`! The `+` operator isn't supposed to modify the object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Animal & Animal::operator+(const string & o);
```

Is invalid. It should be:

```
Animal & operator+(const string & o);
```

Also, your implementation of a simple addition operator, results in the modifications of one of the operands. This is **never** a good thing for an addition operator.

For example:

```
int a, b = 5, c = 3;
a = b + c;
```

That doesn't change the values of either operands; it leaves `b` and `c` untouched, and returns an entirely different instance.

You should therefore not overload the addition operator, but the addition assignment compound operator (`+=`):

```
Animal & operator+=(const string & o);
```

And of course change the implementation and calls to it accordingly:

```
Animal & Animal::operator+=(const string & o) {
    cout << "plus operator \n";
    this->_name=o;
    return *this;
}
```

And:

```
a += "hhh";
```

Answer (score 2):

The declaration of `operator+` inside your class does not need to be qualified, precisely because it is being declared within the class:

```
class Animal {
  // ...
  Animal& operator+(const string& o);
}
```

This qualification is necessary when you *define* the function because you define it outside the class - the compiler needs to know to which class the function belongs.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for the `Animal::` in the prototype, because it's inside the `Animal` class already. Just use:

```
Animal & operator+(const string & o);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Animal::` qualification should be used in the *definition* of a member function, not in the *declaration*. Thus, change your operator declaration into:

```
Animal & operator+(const string & o);
```